# How do you prove that the Galois Group of a radical field extension is always soluble/solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

The question is asking how to prove (not necessarily in high detail but concisely) that the Galois Group (the group of Q-automorphisms of F where Q is the base field and F is a field extension of the base field) of a radical field extension (an extension of a field K that is obtained by adjoining a sequence of nth roots - radicals - of elements) is always soluble/solvable (a group which has a normal series such that each normal factor is abelian).

Thank you

p.s. I am only 17 so please don't make your answer to complicated - cheers.

Comment: Please make the question body self-contained so the title is not necessary to understand the question. Also, writing up what definition of radical extension and solvable group you are familiar with will help people give useful answers.

Comment: Doing that now.

Comment: Done.              random stuff to get 15 characters.

Comment: Geoff Robertson has written a sketch solution, but my immediate reaction is that this is a standard textbook result, and you would do better to read a book about it rather than trying to do it as an exercise. Lots of of people recommend Ian Stewart's book on Galois Theory for example.

Comment: @Derek Holt : It's Geoff Robinson! I certainly agree that it's better to read a proper text book. I responded because the question has a history on Mathoverflow too- although Daniele's age seems to fluctuate somewhat!

Comment: Sorry I'm jet-lagged!

Comment: I am actually 13, but I like to make the question available to more people - hence why I say 17/18, so people of that sort of age will understand too.

Comment: I don't think age is a very good indicator (at all) of what level a person should pitch their answers toward. I think you should replace your p.s. with a brief description of what you know in the field so far. [And I mean very brief: a sentence or two.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rough sketch: You use induction on the degree of the field extension, and it is useful to allow the base field to vary. So we need to consider the case that $F = L[a^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ for some $a$, and some intermediate field $L$, itself a radical extension. Set $b = a^{\frac{1}{n}}$, a particular fixed choice of $n$-th root of $a \in L$. Any field automorphism $\alpha$ of $F$ which fixes $L$ ( ie $\alpha \in {\rm Gal}(F/L) )$ must send $b$ to another $n$-th root of $a$ and this must have the form $\omega b$ for some $n$-th root of unity $\omega$ and we have $\omega \in F$. It follows from this that ${\rm Gal}(F/L)$ is Abelian ( it is isomorphic to a group roots of unity under multiplication, which is certainly Abelian).
    Now the basic idea is to show that ${\rm Gal}(F/Q)/{\rm Gal}(L/Q)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Gal}(F/L)$, and to use inductive assumption that ${\rm Gal}(L/Q)$ is solvable to conclude that ${\rm Gal}(F/Q)$ is solvable.
 However, there are quite a lot of technicalities needed to make the induction work, and it is usual to work with separable normal intermediate extensions, to ensure that they are left invariant under enough automorphisms ( for example, if you don't make some assumptions, it might be that an automorphism of $F$ which fixes $Q$ does not send elements of $L$ back into $L$: eg, think about the case that 
$F = Q[\omega,2^{\frac{1}{3}}]$ where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity and the cube root of $2$ is the real one. Take $L$ to be $F \cap \mathbb{R}$.
Then any automorphism of $F$ which does not fix the real cube root of $2$ must 
send that cube root somewhere outside $L$).

Comment: Is the extension $Q[\omega, 2^{\frac{1}{3}}]$ abelian ?

Comment: No, it isn't. The Galous group is isomorphic to  the symmetric group on $3$ letters.

Comment: When will the extension $Q[\omega, p^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ over $Q$ be abelian then ? Here $p$ is  a prime. Does the answer depend on $n$ ?

Comment: It will not be Abelian for any $n > 2$. This is because there are at most two real $n$-th roots of $p$ ( two if $n$ is even, only one if $n$ is odd). It follows that if $\alpha$ is a real $n$-th root of $p$, then the polynomial $x^{n}-p$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, but does not split over that field.

Comment: I think $Q[\omega,p^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ would be abelian over an unramified extension of $Q$ e.g., over $Q(\omega)$ for any odd $n$. What do you say ?

Comment: It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}[\omega, p^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$.

Comment: Suddenly I am little confused. In your answer you said the radical extension $F=L[a^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ is abelian over $L$. Also we know the the cyclomtomic extension extension $L[\omega]$ is abelian. Therefore their compositum $L[\omega, a^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ is also abelian. So $Q[\omega, p^{\frac{1}{n}}]$ is abelian. I think I am missing something

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that if ${\rm Gal}(M/L)$ is Abelian and ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$ is Abelian, then ${\rm Gal}(M/K)$ is Abelian. that is why Galois theory deals with solvable groups.

Comment: Thank you very much